# Not getting any response while using JavaMail API

Tags: java, email, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email from a webpage to my email id using Gmail smtp server. I tried various answers on stackoverflow. Unfortunately, none of them worked.

```
   `public void sendMail(String msg){

    Properties props= System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtps.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    //props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    //props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");

    Authenticator authenticate= new Authenticator(){
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
            };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Session mailSession= Session.getInstance(props, authenticate);
    mailSession.setDebug(true);

    Message mailMessage= new MimeMessage(mailSession);

    try {
        mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailFrom));
        mailMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mailTo));
        mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
        mailMessage.setText(msg);

        Transport trans= mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        trans.connect("smtp.gmail.com", username, password);
        trans.sendMessage(mailMessage, mailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        trans.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MailSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}`
```

I am trying above written code

`DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.4
  Info:   DEBUG: getProvider() returning 
  javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
  Info:   DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
  Info:   DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false`

And, this is I am getting as an output with no exceptions, no messages and not even an email to my email address.
I am using JavaMail API 1.5.4 Java 8 and GlassFish Server as a localhost server with reference to an online tutorial.

Please help!!

Comment: Fix these [common mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), follow these [Gmail instructions](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmail), and if it still doesn't work, try these [connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).

Comment: So it stops at trying to connect?

Comment: @BillShannon Thank you for your response, I removed common mistakes. But this time I am getting this: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;

Comment: @KarlNicholas Don't know sir nothing happens, the log remains same for long

Comment: Must not be connecting then.

Comment: Did you try the connection debugging tips?  What happened?

Comment: @BillShannon May be, as I have setDebug(true), and I have written also enclosed debug report with question.

Comment: @KarlNicholas May be, as this is the line I am getting in the next line of exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: There are more connection debugging tips, but it doesn't sound like you tried them.  Also, the answer to your question is in the JavaMail FAQ, see if you can find it.

Comment: Well if you're getting a stack trace then by all means post it here, could be helpful ...

Comment: @BillShannon Yes Sir, I tried those by following this link [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/154578/troubleshooting-problems-connecting-to-mail-servers). And in these tips first 2 methods of second section were successful but in third method I am recieving "Bad Parameter 25" for port number 25 and "Bad Parameter 465" for port number 465.

Comment: Now I don't know how to resolve them PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: @KarlNicholas Sir, Here is the log full log which I am getting `Info:   DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.4
Info:   DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
Info:   DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
Info:   DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL true
Severe:   javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;`

Comment: @KarlNicholas  `nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2056)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)`

Comment: @KarlNicholas `at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
 .....
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Comment: @KarlNicholas `Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
 .... at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2020)
 ... 36 more`

Comment: @KarlNicholas `Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
 at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
 at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
 ... 47 more`

Comment: @KarlNicholas These 4-5 comments include the whole server log.

Comment: @Cyrus - I checked against [JavaMail API – Sending email via Gmail SMTP example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) - the code works fine but google doesn't allow JavaMail to use its API. You should probably use a different mail server. I've used SendGrid successfully. Used [com.sun.mail - javax.mail - 1.6.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.sun.mail%7Cjavax.mail%7C1.6.0%7Cjar)

Comment: I don't know why you say that Google doesn't allow JavaMail to use its API.  JavaMail works fine with Gmail.  You either have to [enable less secure apps](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmailauth) or use [OAuth2 authentication](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2).

Comment: @Cyrus, it seems that you didn't read my [connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug), nor did you find the [JavaMail FAQ entry describing the cert path problem](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#installcert).

Comment: @BillShannon Sir, I tried downloading InstallCert but the link is not working.

Comment: Sigh, yes, it looks like the original program has disappeared.  Try the newer version [here](http://s-n-ushakov.blogspot.com/2013/11/yet-another-installcert-for-java-now.html).

Comment: @BillShannon Yes Sir got it Thank You!!

Comment: @BillShannon Thank You Sir, finally I got what I wanted

Comment: @KarlNicholas Thank You Sir, finally I got what I wanted

Comment: @BillShannon -- Well, I never got it to work. Old help file entries don't mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got it right now I am able to send an email. Thank You @BillShanon, @KarlNicholas and Yashashvi Kaushik for your support.
Here is the code that worked for me with my mentioned version of JavaMail Api

```
Properties props= System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");

    Authenticator authenticate= new Authenticator(){
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
            };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Session mailSession= Session.getInstance(props, authenticate);
    mailSession.setDebug(true);


    Message mailMessage= new MimeMessage(mailSession);


    try {
        mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailFrom));
        mailMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mailTo));
        mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
        mailMessage.setText(msg);

        Transport trans= mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        trans.connect("smtp.gmail.com", username, password);
        Transport.send(mailMessage);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MailSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

In addition to this I disabled my Avast Antivirus firewall as this was not allowing my program to connect with my mail id. Hope, this will work for other coders also with same problem.

Comment: Your code contains several of the [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  Please update the code in your post so that the next person who copies your code will get the correct code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not JavaMail, for which I use to a SendGrid account, but some older apache http code that might help you in your debugging. I don't know if it still works, but should do. Note the port difference.

```
    SimpleSMTPHeader header;
    AuthenticatingSMTPClient client;
    server = "smtp.gmail.com";

    client = new AuthenticatingSMTPClient();
    client.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(
                                          new PrintWriter(System.out), true));

    client.connect(server, 587);
    client.ehlo( client.getLocalAddress().getHostName() );
    client.execTLS();

    if (!SMTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(client.getReplyCode()))
    {
        client.disconnect();
        System.err.println("SMTP server refused connection.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    client.auth(AuthenticatingSMTPClient.AUTH_METHOD.LOGIN,  "gmail-email@gmail.com", "password");


    sender = "sender@email.com";
    subject = "A subject";

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "html/DocumentReport.html") );
    client.mail("<email@email.com>");
    String receipient = "recipient@email.com;

    client.addRecipient(receipient);

    writer = client.sendMessageData();

    header = new SimpleSMTPHeader(sender, receipient, subject);
    header.addHeaderField("Mime-Version", "1.0");
    header.addHeaderField("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"");
    header.addHeaderField("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "7bit");


    writer.write(header.toString());
    try {
        Util.copyReader(reader, writer);
    } finally {
        reader.close();             
    }

    writer.close();

    boolean completed = client.completePendingCommand();

    client.logout();

    client.disconnect();
```